# react-native application stuck on splash screen

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, react-native

Recently my app stopped loading.

It builds, the metro loads the dependencies and then nothing happens. It is just stuck on the splash screen.

I am using a real Android device.

I tried running "adb shell input keyevent 82" to bring the developer menu and use the remote debugger, but the developer menu is not prompting out.

And the device is present in adb devices, and can execute commands like "adb shell input keyevent 3" which triggers the home button of the devices.

The metro is as on this picture:

[image: Stuck metro]

Has anyone experienced similar issue or have a clue why it is acting like this ?

**EDIT :**

So far things that helped solve the issue were:

- Restarting the computer
- Commenting the following lines which enable the NavigationService that react-navigation offers.(After the app builds and starts if i uncomment these lines it works again with them)

  ref={navigatorRef => {
        NavigationService.setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef);
     }}

So these solutions help resolving the problem, but does anyone have a clue what is triggering the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Is your  NavigationService class look like this ?

```
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

let _navigator;

function setTopLevelNavigator( navigatorRef ){
    _navigator = navigatorRef;
}

function navigate( routeName, params ){
    _navigator.dispatch(
        NavigationActions.navigate({
            routeName,
            params
        })
    );
}

export default {
    navigate,
    setTopLevelNavigator
};
```

It would be nice if you can provide console log information.

Answer (score 0):

```
My code looks like this:

import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

let _navigator;

export const setTopLevelNavigator = (navigatorRef) => {
    console.log("WILL SET TOP LEVEL NAVIGATOR WITH", navigatorRef);
    _navigator = navigatorRef;
}

export const navigate = (routeName, params) => {
    _navigator.dispatch(
        NavigationActions.navigate({
            routeName,
            params
        })
    )
}

export default{
    navigate,
    setTopLevelNavigator
}
```

I have exported the functions as well since i was having a different approach before and actually forgot to remove the export from them afterwards.

Do you think that maybe that can be the cause of the problem ?
When the issue is present i do not get console log errors since the app doesn't move past the splash screen and doesn't provide developer menu, so i cannot debug in that state.